# Notification icon on pinned Chrome apps (Windows)

Tags: google-chrome

I am using mattermost as a pinned chrome app in a separate window accordingly to [here](https://www.camya.com/chrome-app-shortcut-how-it-still-works/)

Now I know that there are also real clients for this app but our company hasn't allowed it yet.

Is there a way to get a notification marker like on Outlook when a new mail pops in?

As some of my co-workers are not keen to using an application which doesn't show some kind of notification when new messages arrive.

My only thoughts till now is building a standalone integration into something like electron or nw.js but this involves somewhat a lot of work as I don't know those "runtimes" really well and if its even possible to show a notification icon.